# Backbone / Dropzone : How to properly dispose a Dropzone instance

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, dropzone.js

My application instanciates lots of dropzone elements. Through the navigation, I instanciate Dropzone, but when users leaves to an other page, I need to properly dispose the Dropzones to keep my document events / DOM clean.

I use amd version of Dropzone within a backbone / requirejs application.

The documentation says to call disable() method to remove all dropzone event listeners. I call disable method, then I remove the element from the DOM. Is this a safe way to properly clean the Dropzone? Does Dropzone module still keep references to this removed Dropzone element?

Here is the code I use to render a dropzone element "as a view" in my backbone application. I need to make "remove" function properly clean the Dropzone instance :

```
define(['backbone','dropzone-amd-module'], function(Backbone, Dropzone){
    // Prevent Dropzone from auto discovering this element:
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = false;
    // This is useful when you want to create the
    // Dropzone programmatically later
    // Disable auto discover for all elements:
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'dropzone',
        dropzone_reference: null,
        render: function(){
            this.initDropzone();
            return this;
        },
        initDropzone: function(){
            // init dropzone (avoid to init more than once!)
            if( !this.dropzone_reference)this.dropzone_reference = new Dropzone(this.el, this.options);
        },
        remove: function(){
            // remove dropzone instance
            this.dropzone_reference.disable();
            Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbones `view.remove()`:

```
remove: function() {
  this._removeElement();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
},
```

removes the view's element from DOM.

As you said, the drop method does remove event handlers:

> If you do not need a dropzone anymore, just call .disable() on the object. This will remove all event listeners on the element

Since `view.remove()` removes the element itself from DOM, even `.disable()` doesn't seem necessary.

The only thing having a reference to your dropzone module is the view's `dropzone_reference` property. When there are no references to the view, it'll be garbage collected, leaving the dropzone module with no references, which will in turn get garbage collected.

Just make sure you don't keep any references to the destroyed view.

Comment: Well I forgot to make the dropzone reference null. Ok. But I don't need to call .disable() when the view is removed? You mean that backbone will automatically remove all event listeners Dropzone added to the view's element, and all event listener added to elements created within the view's el?

Comment: @Simmoniz the event handlers are added in the elements itself/delegated to a parent (in this case the view element). When this element is removed from DOM, you don't need to worry about the handlers anymore becuase they are gone with the element. Also you don't need to set dropzone instance to `null`, when there are no reference to the view, view will be removed from memory. That leaves dropzone with no references to it, so it'll be removed also.

Comment: sorry for my late feedback. Sure, your answer was clear and helpful! It confirmed that my app won't get in trouble later that was my main worry. Thanks!